# Typesafe config loads wrong configuration

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

So the problem is really simple and I hope solution will be as well.

So basically I have two configuration files `application.conf` and `dev.conf`. I'm passing my config files from command line like that `sbt -Dconfig.file=dev.conf`.

The problem is when I use `ConfigFactory.load` from main object(the one which `extends App`) it loads config I passed via command line(in this case `dev.conf`), but when I load the config from different object it loads default `application.conf`.

Can I load somehow config passed from arguments from any object?

Comment: It is not clear how do you run your application in both cases. You probably know that regardless of how it is done on the surface, it boils down to a `java -cp classpath your.SomeClass` invocation which starts the JVM. As long as the `config.file` system property is set to `dev.conf`, usually through a command line argument for the `java` binary (`java -Dconfig.file=dev.conf`), it does not matter where `ConfigFactory.load()` is called, because the system property will be the same across your entire app since it is a piece of global state.

Comment: What I mean is, it is important that you pass the system property correctly to your application, because it is the only reason why it could work for one main class and fail for another.

Comment: in both cases I run application `sbt -Dconfig.file="dev.conf"`, then inside of sbt I use `runMain ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run your application with the `runMain` SBT task, then [by default](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Running-Project-Code.html) SBT won't create a separate JVM for your code. This has several consequences around the application lifecycle, and of course with regard to system properties as well.

In general, your approach *should* work, as long as your build configuration does not enable [forking](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Forking.html). However, I think the better approach would be to actually rely on forking and specify the system property explicitly. This is guaranteed to work. To do this, you need to set the `fork` setting in the `run` task to `true`, and then add a JVM command line option:

```
Compile / run / fork := true,
Compile / run / javaOptions += "-Dconfig.file=dev.conf",
```

Don't forget to restart SBT after that. You won't need to pass the `config.file` property to SBT with this approach; rather, it is controlled by the `javaOptions` setting, as in the example above.